# Android getResources().getStringArray() variables

Tags: android, string, variables

I have an xml file, where there are strings and string-arrays. I have a class where I click on a listitem, and in the other class I list other items. In the xml there are string which names are the clicked items modified name, and the values are the string-arrays name. I have found a solution how to add a variable to the getResources(9.getStringArray() but it doesn't work. The program starts, but when I click any of the listitem my activity just stops working.
My class file:

```
String artistpicked = extras.getString("artist");
String[] firstW = artistpicked.split(" ");
firstW[0] = firstW[0].trim();
String albumSearch = firstW[0] + "_code";
int getRes = getResources().getIdentifier(albumSearch, "string", getPackageName());
String setRes = String.valueOf(getRes);
int getRes2 = getResources().getIdentifier(setRes, "array", getPackageName());
String[] albums = getResources().getStringArray(getRes2);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, albums));
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.albumName);
t.setText(setRes);
```

The TextView is there to check the variables. The albumSearch gives "modifiedartistpicked_code", it's good. The getRes gives the value of from the xml ("something_array"), the setRes gives it's actual id number (which the getStringArray requires). The getRes2 gives the same as getRes it's just there to check that it works fine. When I comment out the next two lines, the String albums[], and setListAdapter then the program works but it doesn't list the items.

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="artists_array">
        <item>code1 example</item>
        <item>code2 example</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="code1_array">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="code2_array">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="code1_code">code1_array</string>
    <string name="code2_code">code2_array</string>
</resources>
```

I hope I was able to write what I would like to do, and what is the problem :)

**Update:**

@Marc Bernstein: Because I don't know it's code1_array. First I made many if and when the picked item was x, then I read the R.array.x_array, etc...

But I have got what was the problem, there were capital letters int he name of the strings in xml. Thats why I hate xml, the problem is always there :) This xml was just an example, the original is much greater that's why no one was able to help. Next time I will be much more cautious.

And also I made it now more simplier because you have right it was too complicated.

Comment: I have to say, after reading it a few times, I really have no idea what you're trying to do. To help figure out the problem, you should debug your app, show the LogCat window in Eclipse, and when the app force closes, you should see a red block of text detailing an exception that occured, causing the force close. Look within that block for the first reference to one of your .java files, followed by a :<x>, where <x> is some number showing the line in which the exception occured.

Answer (score 51):

The culprit is most likely

```
String[] albums = getResources().getStringArray(getRes2);
```

Instead of doing

```
int getRes2 = getResources().getIdentifier(setRes, "array", getPackageName());
String[] albums = getResources().getStringArray(getRes2);
```

Why not just use

```
String[] albums = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.code1_array);
```

?

Anyway, from what you posted, I don't think the "array" identifier actually exists within your strings.xml file. I see a code1_array & code2_array.

Answer (score 6):

It's because it tries to determine dynamically the array it wants to use.
The id from `String[] albums = getResources().getStringArray(`**`R.array.code1_array`**`);` is given, let say, at user input, some spinner/edittext box.
This is instead of using a database, just using some strings from xml file.

Comment: Thanks, but in update there is what was the problem. The names in xml were just examples (it was easier and shorter), and in the real xml there was a capital letter what is a big problem in xml :)